# Drupal 7 ajax call

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I'm beginner with drupal, I use drupal 7.x and I would like to create a simple ajax call.

I have a template file and I have a button in it with a javascript function in onclick method.

```
<input type='button' onclick='doajax()'>
<div id='ajaxresponsediv'></div>
```

In the js file:

```
function doajax()
{
   jQuery.get(url,function(data) {
   jQuery("#ajaxresponsediv").html(data);
});
}
```

Ok it's a simple thing. But what do I have to code in .module file ? What will be the url variable in my code? How do I implement the callback function (for example I would like to print simply 'Hello' into ajaxresponsediv ) ? Do I have to register something in mymodule_menu() function? Thanks for the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to register a menu. Hope the below examples help you.

https://clikfocus.com/blog/simple-ajax-example-for-drupal-6-and-7
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-in-drupal-using-jquery